# Is it fine to use one of those tower power outlet?

Tags: electrical, electronics

I have a total of only 4 wall outlets in my room, currently, all of them are occupied by a power strip or power tap totaling 12 total plugs. It's a bit of a mess despite my attempts at cable management.

So I was thinking of getting one of those tower power outlet with 12 gangs. At most, I'll use 6 out of 12 powering my PC, monitor, router, access point, fan and phone charger. Is this advisable or not? I did some calculations and the total watt for all these devices is less than what is rated for the tower power outlet but I got confused with the ampere rating. Any help or advice is appreciated

Comment: I will assume a 15 amp circuit.  On a 15 amp circuit you are allowed to around 1400 watts, 120 volts times 12 amps.  A circuit is all the outlets and lights on/controlled by a breaker.  Electrical stuff bought from amazon/ebay might not be safe to use.  All electrical devices used in North America must have a UL/ETL/CSA label, not just a CE label.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing for the same voltage, then watts are perfectly fine for comparison.  However, Power (watts) = Voltage (volts) x Current (amps).

Assuming that the circuit breaker does not flip at the moment and you are still going to be using the same devices, then it's safe to assume it won't flip afterward.

As mentioned by @crip659, you should use a unit that is certified for your country.  Cheap things from ebay, ali*** and temu may not be reliable.  I had one socket where the grip was so ridiculous that plugs would just fall out.

Comment: Momentary current demand can be well below peak current demand. Breaker may indeed flip later. Of course one should avoid loading the circuit close to where the breaker would blow, to reduce risk it it fails.

Answer (score 1):

If your existing receptacles are connected to a single breaker in the panel, then you won't overload the circuit and trip the breaker. It's possible, and even likely, though, that the receptacles are wired into two or more breakers to ensure that the loads are spread more evenly.

In order to test this out, you could ***temporarily*** daisy chain all of your power strips off of one single outlet, plugging everything into that monstrosity, then turn it all on. If the breaker (at the panel) trips, you know you can't use that outlet for everything. While the breaker is tripped, plug something like a lamp or radio into the other receptacles in the room to see if any of them are still live. If any are live, you can split the load over those two different circuits. Get two of your "tower" power strips and plug it into receptacles on the separate breakers.

If your power strips are of decent quality, they may have a circuit breaker built in that may have tripped, shutting the whole shebang down. If so, maybe rearrange your test setup to use one without its own breaker as the "master" plugged into the wall. This should help prevent a more "local" trip by minimizing the loads on those with their own breakers.